# Loading user or custom CSS to a running website. on IE for restyling

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am involved recently in a project to restyle a certain published website. I have no access to the code and the CSS files. what I can to do is to load my custom local CSS as a new "user stylesheet" into firefox or chrome using the extension [Web developer toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) which is available on chrome, opera and firefox.

For a reason, "Web developer toolbar" offer a great feature called [Add User Style Sheet] which enable me to load my local CSS and tweak it using firebug to restyle the page as needed.

but of course some tweaks are necessary to do over IE and there is no tool like "Web developer toolbar" over IE. I know there is a way to load a user style sheet from Internet options > accessibility. but it is very dummy, specially when switching from various IE versions using the built-in IE developer tool. and of course that user style sheet will be active only when restarting IE!! ... so it doesn't make sense doing modification on my CSS and restart to see the affected modification !!

Until the time we decide to eliminate IE forever, I am wondering. if there is a way/tool to load my custom CSS over IE and tweak it from outside IE and just reload it? or by refreshing the page[F5]?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Why don’t you have access to the code, if you’re tasked with reworking that site? That’s quite a strange condition … Anyway, a bookmarklet that disables/removes all linked/embedded stylesheets, and then adds a `link` element to your own stylesheet might work. Or, if this is just for a few documents, I might just save the HTML code and edit those local copies to include my stylesheets in the first place …

Comment: yes it is strange but this is the case i am facing right now. it is not that easy saving the html and CSS and restyle it locally. the page have a lot of javascript and hidden panels. saving the page in HTML wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It wont be easy or quick but the best solution for you r problem would be to do your css styling with IE code inspector. I know its not as good as Firefox or chrome but you will at least be able to see what works and what doesn't. You can ofcouse copy and paste directly out of IE code inspector into your stylesheet but if you refresh you would have to insert all the new styles again.